# Change the colour of the 2nd column by comparing it with the 1st column

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfzXC.png)

If there is a change in the number in the column, its colour should get change as well. 
There are 7 columns.

Compare 1st column with the second. If the numbers are changed, its colour should get change.

Example in first row "134", "139" then "139" value colour should get change.
In second row "4" "4" is repeated, then its colour should not get change.

```
<table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;" colspan="2"><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search Here" title="Type in a name"></th>
        <th colspan="7"> asfdasdf</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><select class="ui dropdown" id="myselection">
                <option value="One">Readvon</option>
                <option value="Two">sdctry</option>
                <option value="Three">scv</option>
                <option value="four">sdv</option>
            </select></th>
        <th>Nov_2013</th>
        <th>March_2014</th>
        <th>Dec_2015</th>
        <th>Nov_2017</th>
        <th>April_2018</th>
        <th>Feb_2019</th>
        <th>April_2019</th>


    </tr>
</table>
<div id="showOne">
    <table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='color:red'>Total</td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td>139</td>
            <td>137</td>
            <td>158</td>
            <td>144</td>
            <td>146</td>
            <td>140</td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Aadc</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>4</td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Asdvacific</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>33</td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Eafcdpe</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>50</td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Inasdca</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>3</td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>MsCDNA</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>6</td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>NortScerica</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>44</td>
            <td>49</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>40</td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>SouacAmerica</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: Please take your time to rewrite your question, I've read it 4 times and I still don't understand what you want to achieve exactly, also what have you already tried yourself? :)

Comment: Have you written any Javascript code, so that will check, where you are doing wrong!!!

Comment: not writen js for the code

Comment: Refer this `HTMLTableElement` api, it will help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement

Comment: When you say column, are you refering to whole column or just the table cell on the 2nd column?

Comment: Your description isn't understandable please edit your post

Comment: @addo.lou whole column

Comment: @vineet, I was taking a closer look at your HTML and I'm under the impression you are doing 2 tables, 1 for the table headers and one for the table cells. You should just have 1 table that includes both header and cells. Search for <thead> and <tbody> table elements for better understanfing.

Comment: Yeah, that's true I agree with @addo.lou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like below. Read about [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement). You have to access rows first and then columns. Compare text in each column...

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var rows = table[0].rows
var rowsLength = rows.length;
var columns;
var columnsLength;

for (var i = 0; i < rowsLength; i++) {
  columns = rows[i].cells;
  columnsLength = columns.length;
  // We don't need first column, as it contains the text
  for (var j = 1; j < columnsLength - 1; j++) {
    if (parseInt(columns[j].innerText) != parseInt(columns[j + 1].innerText)) {
      columns[j + 1].style.color = 'green';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2' style='color:red'>Total</td>
    <td>134</td>
    <td>139</td>
    <td>137</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>144</td>
    <td>146</td>
    <td>140</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Aadc</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Asdvacific</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Eafcdpe</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Inasdca</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>MsCDNA</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>NortScerica</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>SouacAmerica</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```